# how to filter list of node in neo4j based on property

Tags: filter, neo4j, cypher, nodes

I want to eliminate out those paths which does not starts with " Media Topics", Name = " Media Topics" is the property of node inside languages.

Here is my query

```
MATCH path = (top:Taxonomy)-[:IS_CHILD_OF*0..]->(taxo)
WHERE NOT ()-[:IS_CHILD_OF]->(top)
WITH DISTINCT [node in nodes(path) | [(language)-[:IN_LANGUAGE{lang:'en'}]->(node) | language][0]] as languages//chn
ORDER BY size(languages) DESC
return [n in reverse(languages) | n.name ] as nodesInPath
```

here is my output

```
["Media Topic", "crime, law and justice", "judiciary", "court", "trial (court)", "sentencing (criminal)", "capital punishment"]

["Media Topic", "crime, law and justice", "judiciary", "court", "trial (court)", "sentencing (criminal)", "fine (penalty)"]

["Media Topic", "crime, law and justice", "judiciary", "court", "trial (court)", "sentencing (criminal)", "prison"]

["Media Topic", "crime, law and justice", "judiciary", "court", "trial (court)", "sentencing (criminal)", "court-ordered psychiatric treatment"]

["crime, law and justice", "judiciary", "court", "trial (court)", "pre-trial"]
```

Now last row should not be printed since it does not starts with "Media Topic"

Answer (score 0):

```
MATCH path = (top:Taxonomy)-[:IS_CHILD_OF*0..]->(taxo) 
WHERE NOT ()-[:IS_CHILD_OF]->(top) 
WITH DISTINCT [node in nodes(path) | [(language)-[:IN_LANGUAGE{lang:'en'}]->(node) | language][0]] as languages 
ORDER BY size(languages) DESC
WITH [n in reverse(languages) | n.name ] as nodesInPath 
WHERE nodesInPath[0]= "Media Topic"
RETURN nodesInPath
```

i have not much your altered your query since i am not very what you are trying to achieve here. But i do feel this query can be improved performance wise. 
i filtered the final list you got with the condition that the zeroth element should be "Media Topic" . 
if you could give more details about your  graph . I may be more helpful .